# Client Side Validation Using Custom Validator FluentValidation MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side, fluentvalidation

I have seen many examples of using FluentValidation here but none seem to fit my need. I have an existing server side implementation and based on answers here, I am convinced I have to change my implementation to get it work client side. One reason is because I can't set a ValidationType which seems required for the client side. I am having trouble converting the code so I can use it client side as well. I am submitting a list of File objects and want client side validation that the file extensions are either .pdf or .doc.

Global - Many examples here show a much more complicated Configure

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
}
```

Model - I've simplified my model to show that I have at least one property and a collection

```
[Validator(typeof(MyCustomValidator))]
public class MyCustomModel
{
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> MyFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Model Validator - I have a separate validator for the collection

```
public class MyCustomModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyCustomModel>
{
    public MyCustomModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SubmitDate)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Date Required");           

        RuleFor(x => x.MyFiles)  
            .SetCollectionValidator(new MyFileValidator())
            .Where(x => x != null);
    }
}
```

Collection Validator - This should check a file for a valid extension

```
public class MyFileValidator : AbstractValidator<HttpPostedFileBase>
{
    public MyFileValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x)              
           .Must(x => x.IsValidFileType())
           .WithMessage("Invalid File Type")
    }  
}

public static bool IsValidFileType(this HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var extensions = { ".pdf", ".doc" };

    return extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName.ToLower()));
}
```

Controller - Just showing the basics

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(DefaultParameters parameters)
{
    var model = new MyCustomModel();

    return this.View(model);
}   

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(MyCustomModel model)
{   
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View("Index", model);
    }   
}
```

View - I am allowing 5 uploads per submission

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubmitDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TextBoxFor

@for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileSubmissions[i], new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FileSubmissions[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you would change it to clientside? Not all validations should run clientside. Maybe you can get it working using the regex validation method instead of the Must method which is performed clientside according to the docs.

Comment: It seems pretty standard that any time a server call can be avoided it should be. If something can be done client side then it should be done. In this case, I am using the FILE HTML tag. without client side, if I fail server side and my view is returned. The FILE element has an error but the actual element is blank because setting a FILE element programmatically is forbidden. Not only am I making a server call that is unnecessary but then it is completely unclear what caused the error since I can't show the data.

Comment: I get your point. Maybe this link can give you further info. http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/351248 Also I think I stumbled across a blog post by J SKinner that does gives a bit more info, yet I cant find it right now. Did you look into the Matches-method which can perform regex validation clientside? I still think this is your best bet.